# Yii2 - find max based year in active record

Tags: php, yii2

I want to select maximum an field which is integer in my db.

So, First I try the orthodok's way :

```
SELECT max(a.nomor_surat) as max FROM request a
WHERE YEAR(a.tanggal_persetujuan) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Works. (In my case : max = 3)

Now, using AR,

```
Request::find()->select('max(nomor_surat) as max')->where(['YEAR(tanggal_persetujuan)' => 'YEAR(CURDATE())' ])->scalar();
```

I got max = 1, 
How AR interpretatioin them correctly ?

Pleas Advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Request::find()
    ->andWhere(['YEAR([[tanggal_persetujuan]])' => new \yii\db\Expression('YEAR(CURDATE())')])
    ->max('[[nomor_surat]]');
```